# Testing openGL / libGL library on CentOS 6.6

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I think I may have a problem with my installation of openGL.  I am working on a CentOS 6.6 cluster.  I'm looking for canonical "hello world" type examples of openGL code.

It appears that these [examples](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html) are 20+ years old and don't compile.

E.g.

```
~$ gcc cube.c -lglut
/tmp/ccRTbnOw.o: In function `init':
cube.c:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `gluPerspective'
cube.c:(.text+0x325): undefined reference to `gluLookAt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The openGL was installed in the mesa rpm :

```
mesa-libGL-devel-10.1.2-2.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: AFAIK `glut` is no longer shipped with mesa (as per the note on their download page: https://www.mesa3d.org/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

Those are linker errors, it looks like it's compiling just fine.

You have to link against `libGL` & `libGLU` too:

```
gcc cube.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU
```